# Is Backtrack is derivative of Ubuntu?

Tags: derivatives

I have read somewhere taht Backtrack is a Ubuntu Linux.

I am confused. I know quite well that Backtrack is a Linux, but apparently Backtrack is also an Ubuntu. Please, clarify me this.

Answer (score 3):

Backtrack is an unofficial Ubuntu based distro. It IS linux of course! but not Ubuntu.

Comment: ohhh ohky so can you tell me how to install update manager and package in administration?
Is it possive in backtrack??

Comment: This is not an issue to be covered here ;)

Comment: Backtrack uses Ubuntu as a base, but it is highly moddified, including a custom kernel. As such it is off topic here, try asking the backtrack project.

Comment: ohky thnx for telling me