# Is Kali Linux based on Ubuntu?

Tags: debian

I remember reading in another thread ([Is Backtrack is derivative of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263949/is-backtrack-is-derivative-of-ubuntu)) that Kali Linux is based on Debian. Can someone clarify?

Comment: It appears to be "Debian-based" in recent versions.

Comment: I was clear about the Child/Inheritor situation of Ubuntu and Kali from Debian. But the answer given in another [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263949/is-backtrack-is-derivative-of-ubuntu) confused me.

Comment: As your question is not specifically about Ubuntu it's off topic here you could ask on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) stack exchange site or in [Unix, Linux and OS Chat](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=434) on the Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the guidance regarding correct place to post this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Kali Linux is [based on Debian](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=kali). Ubuntu is also based on Debian.

Source: [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Not, it is not. It is based on Debian.

> Kali Linux is a Debian-derived Linux distribution designed for digital forensics and penetration testing.

The only thing related with Backtrack is that the authors of Backtrack has participated on this project too.

> From the creators of BackTrack comes Kali Linux

You should read [their website](http://www.kali.org/) and [their Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking, here.

Ubuntu is based on Debian. Anything based upon Ubuntu is therefore **also** based on Debian.

Kali is **definitely** a Debian-based distribution (which is the term used to describe any child/inheritor distribution of Debian, including Ubuntu which is based directly off Debian, and Mint, which is based off Ubuntu and therefore on Debian)

Kali **may** be based upon Ubuntu.

Comment: It is a simple question. Additionally, thanks for Sharing this information.

Comment: My point is that the question is slightly ambiguous. It is not clear between the title and the content whether there is an understanding that Ubuntu itself is based upon Debian, and that was the clarification that I sought. I'm glad that you were able to find the information at least slightly helpful.